# Solarized, Win-32 Console Vim Italicized Consolas Font

Tags: windows, vim, console, color-scheme, italic

I am having issues with having Solarized italicize the font in the Win-32 Console correctly. Everything is fine if I turn off italicizing using `let g:solarized_italic = 0`; however when this option is on, any text that is affected (and should be italicized) are not italicized and have their background colour set incorrectly.

I've set the font for both command prompt and Vim in 'Defaults' and 'Properties' to Consolas, and Consolas is indeed being used as the font. I suspect that it's something to do with how the default font is chosen and how that interacts with Solarized; however I don't know how to fix this.

Any help and advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows console doesn't support italics. You're better off using Gvim or running Vim in another console/terminal emulator like [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) or [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/).

Comment: I can live with not having italics and bold, but I guess there are enough advantages of using these terminals that are supposedly a lot better than the Windows console. I will look into them a bit more; thanks.